# Regexp assistance

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match

I'm not very experience with regexp and have been struggling to match all of my use cases with any attempts I have made, I was wondering if someone could suggest a match that may cover the following scenarios. I need to extract the volume i.e. 250ml from the string.

- Vanilla Blossom 250ml body wash
- Vanilla Blossom 250 ml body wash
- Vanilla Blossom body wash 250ml
- 250ml Vanilla Blossom body wash
- Vanilla Blossom 20g soap
- Vanilla Blossom 20 g soap

Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: What about `20g` and `20 g`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = ['Vanilla Blossom 250ml body wash',
  'Vanilla Blossom 250 ml body wash',
  'Vanilla Blossom body wash 250ml',
  '250ml Vanilla Blossom body wash',
  'Vanilla Blossom 20g soap',
  'Vanilla Blossom 20 g soap',
  'Vanilla Blossom 20 dag soap',
  'Vanilla Blossom 20dag soap'
];

let reg = /(?:\d+[ ]{0,1})(?:ml|g)/i;

console.log(arr.map(str => str.match(reg)));
```

Comment: is there a way to ignore the text if it isn't say ml or g?

Comment: @user1372212 I edited my answer to catch only ml and g afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do the job:

```js
var test = [
    'Vanilla Blossom 250ml body wash',
    'Vanilla Blossom 250 ml body wash',
    'Vanilla Blossom body wash 250ml',
    '250ml Vanilla Blossom body wash',
    'Vanilla Blossom 20g soap',
    'Vanilla Blossom 20 g soap',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.match(/\d+\s*ml/)
  }));
```